# Trying to animate text in wpf like its being written out by hand

Tags: wpf, animation, text, handwriting

I'm trying to animate text using Blend so the visibility of a text block will appear in such a way that it looks like its being hand written. I tried creating a storyboard and then turned my textblock into a path, and then converted that back and started working with the path points at key frames on the new story board and spreading out the spacing.
The thing is, it just does not appear very natural looking. Is there a different way I can do this so it looks like someones hand writing the text in a more natural manner

```
    <UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ec="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/controls" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="ControlLibrary.mScrapeBottomIntro"
x:Name="UserControl"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="480">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="mScrapeAnimation">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="path">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="path1">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="path2">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="path3">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="path4">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource mScrapeAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Path x:Name="path" Data="M15.445302,-1.9852335E-23 C15.679676,-1.9852335E-23 15.871082,0.11718692 16.019521,0.35156122 C16.167958,0.58593649 16.285145,0.89062247 16.371083,1.2656187 C16.45702,1.6406187 16.51952,2.0585854 16.558583,2.5195187 C16.597645,2.9804558 16.617176,3.4296723 16.617176,3.8671682 C16.617176,4.1171689 16.61327,4.3554489 16.605458,4.5820084 C16.597645,4.8085717 16.585927,5.0234144 16.570302,5.2265364 C17.226551,5.0702891 17.894519,4.9101337 18.574206,4.7460701 C19.253894,4.5820103 19.910143,4.4218549 20.542955,4.2656037 C21.175767,4.1093564 21.769517,3.9609197 22.324204,3.8202935 C22.878891,3.6796711 23.35936,3.5546717 23.765609,3.4452953 C24.609357,3.2265483 25.347638,3.0234243 25.980452,2.8359234 C26.613262,2.6484262 27.15623,2.4843645 27.609357,2.3437383 C28.06248,2.2031159 28.441386,2.0898352 28.746075,2.0038963 C29.05076,1.9179611 29.289041,1.8749926 29.460918,1.8749907 C29.820291,1.8749926 30.062478,1.9257736 30.18748,2.0273336 C30.312478,2.1288975 30.374978,2.3124904 30.37498,2.5781121 C30.374978,2.8749876 30.101541,3.2304546 29.554668,3.6445131 C29.007792,4.0585754 28.304667,4.4960732 27.445294,4.9570065 C26.585918,5.4179437 25.621075,5.8788789 24.550765,6.3398121 C23.480453,6.8007493 22.417954,7.2226222 21.363267,7.6054308 C20.30858,7.9882433 19.316393,8.3163667 18.386707,8.5898009 C17.45702,8.8632371 16.703114,9.0390174 16.124989,9.1171421 C16.046863,10.070262 15.984363,11.085882 15.937489,12.164002 C15.890614,13.242121 15.855457,14.288991 15.832021,15.304611 C15.808582,16.320231 15.789051,17.25382 15.773427,18.105379 C15.757801,18.956937 15.749989,19.624902 15.74999,20.109275 C15.749989,21.906141 15.835926,23.581914 16.007802,25.136593 C16.179677,26.691273 16.371083,28.070173 16.58202,29.273292 C16.792958,30.476411 16.984364,31.472499 17.156239,32.261558 C17.328114,33.050617 17.414051,33.577958 17.414051,33.843581 C17.414051,34.265454 17.351551,34.640452 17.226551,34.968576 C17.101551,35.296699 16.843739,35.460761 16.453114,35.460761 C16.078114,35.460761 15.671864,35.148262 15.234365,34.523265 C14.796864,33.898269 14.382802,32.960773 13.992178,31.710779 C13.601552,30.460786 13.277334,28.910012 13.019523,27.058459 C12.761709,25.206906 12.632803,23.04676 12.632804,20.578022 C12.632803,19.828026 12.648428,19.019436 12.679679,18.152253 C12.710928,17.28507 12.749991,16.390543 12.796866,15.468673 C12.84374,14.546802 12.90624,13.613213 12.984366,12.667906 C13.06249,11.722598 13.148428,10.796821 13.242179,9.8905757 C11.632805,10.296824 10.109368,10.613228 8.6718691,10.83979 C7.2343696,11.066351 5.9609329,11.179632 4.8515591,11.179632 C4.1484346,11.179632 3.5039035,11.081976 2.9179664,10.886664 C2.3320295,10.691353 1.8203109,10.460885 1.3828115,10.195262 C0.94531162,9.929638 0.60546809,9.6483894 0.36328051,9.3515159 C0.12109341,9.0546424 -2.6449501E-07,8.8124561 4.3328661E-13,8.624957 C-2.6449501E-07,8.2499608 0.12499965,7.9804309 0.37499958,7.8163673 C0.62499933,7.6523075 0.9765616,7.5702767 1.4296861,7.5702748 C2.1484358,7.5702767 2.9648416,7.5273081 3.8789037,7.4413692 C4.7929654,7.355434 5.7773397,7.2382471 6.8320266,7.0898084 C7.8867129,6.9413736 8.9960877,6.761687 10.160149,6.5507486 C11.324211,6.3398141 12.515617,6.1093465 13.734366,5.8593458 C13.84374,5.0156019 13.96874,4.2343558 14.109366,3.5156075 C14.24999,2.796863 14.394521,2.1796785 14.542959,1.6640542 C14.691396,1.1484337 14.839833,0.74218571 14.988271,0.44531028 C15.136708,0.14843676 15.289051,-1.9852335E-23 15.445302,-1.9852335E-23 z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="129.953,222.14,0,222.399" RenderTransformOrigin="6.72915648883858,0.654329162094918" Stretch="Fill" Width="30.375" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path1" Data="M15.398426,4.4025168E-07 C14.710926,4.4025168E-07 13.933583,0.10156243 13.066396,0.30468642 C12.199209,0.50781041 11.289053,0.79687147 10.335929,1.1718696 C9.3828045,1.5468677 8.4140552,1.9999905 7.4296808,2.5312378 C6.4453064,3.0624852 5.4960883,3.6562322 4.5820264,4.3124789 C3.6679645,4.9687257 2.8164025,5.6796596 2.0273424,6.4452808 C1.2382804,7.210902 0.56249964,8.0155855 -3.5527132E-15,8.8593313 C1.4062491,8.5624578 2.80859,8.2030846 4.2070266,7.7812117 C5.6054632,7.3593388 6.9413999,6.9101222 8.2148365,6.4335621 C9.4882732,5.957002 10.671866,5.464817 11.765615,4.957007 C12.859365,4.449197 13.808583,3.9609182 14.61327,3.4921705 C15.417957,3.0234229 16.046863,2.5820188 16.499987,2.1679584 C16.953112,1.7538979 17.179674,1.398431 17.179674,1.1015574 C17.179674,0.83593377 17.019518,0.58593502 16.699206,0.35156119 C16.378894,0.11718736 15.9453,4.4025168E-07 15.398426,4.4025168E-07 z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="159.506,233.952,0,237.188" RenderTransformOrigin="10.1774278243034,1.2857142933418" Stretch="Fill" Width="17.18" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path2" Data="M19.593736,-2.4815418E-24 C20.406236,-2.4815418E-24 21.101548,0.082030841 21.679672,0.24609252 C22.257797,0.41015421 22.726547,0.63671558 23.085921,0.92577664 C23.445296,1.2148377 23.710921,1.5546798 23.882796,1.9453028 C24.054671,2.3359259 24.140608,2.7577988 24.140608,3.2109215 C24.140608,3.9765427 23.796859,4.7734137 23.109359,5.6015346 C22.421859,6.4296555 21.523422,7.2343389 20.414048,8.015585 C19.304674,8.7968312 18.062487,9.5351087 16.687488,10.230418 C15.312489,10.925727 13.933584,11.535099 12.550772,12.058534 C11.16796,12.581969 9.8593675,12.996029 8.6249933,13.300715 C7.3906191,13.605401 6.3593717,13.757744 5.5312472,13.757744 C5.0781225,13.757744 4.6992165,13.61712 4.3945292,13.335871 C4.0898419,13.054622 3.8906233,12.734312 3.7968733,12.374938 C3.3124987,13.468683 3.0703113,14.523365 3.0703113,15.538985 C3.0703113,16.085857 3.160155,16.605386 3.3398424,17.097571 C3.5195298,17.589756 3.8124983,18.019441 4.2187481,18.386627 C4.6249978,18.753813 5.1601537,19.042874 5.8242158,19.25381 C6.4882779,19.464747 7.3046817,19.570215 8.273431,19.570215 C9.6640551,19.570215 11.070304,19.382716 12.492178,19.007718 C13.914052,18.63272 15.30077,18.132722 16.652332,17.507725 C18.003894,16.882728 19.300768,16.156169 20.542954,15.328049 C21.785141,14.499928 22.921859,13.624932 23.953108,12.703062 C24.343733,12.359313 24.632795,12.187439 24.820295,12.187439 C24.976545,12.187439 25.05467,12.289001 25.05467,12.492125 C25.05467,12.663999 24.996076,12.894467 24.878889,13.183528 C24.761702,13.472589 24.58592,13.765556 24.351546,14.06243 C23.882796,14.656177 23.312484,15.292893 22.640609,15.972577 C21.968735,16.652261 21.226548,17.328039 20.414048,17.99991 C19.601549,18.671782 18.722643,19.31631 17.777331,19.933494 C16.832019,20.550679 15.851551,21.097551 14.835927,21.574111 C13.820302,22.050671 12.773428,22.429576 11.695304,22.710824 C10.61718,22.992073 9.5390552,23.132697 8.4609309,23.132697 C7.4921816,23.132697 6.5039028,23.01551 5.496091,22.781136 C4.4882792,22.546763 3.5781235,22.167858 2.765624,21.644423 C1.9531245,21.120988 1.2890625,20.433492 0.7734378,19.581934 C0.25781314,18.730375 8.049478E-07,17.687412 8.049478E-07,16.453043 C8.049478E-07,14.999925 0.32812559,13.58587 0.98437517,12.210877 C1.6406247,10.835883 2.5039054,9.539015 3.5742172,8.320271 C4.6445291,7.1015271 5.8710908,5.9843452 7.2539005,4.9687252 C8.6367121,3.9531053 10.05468,3.0742034 11.507804,2.3320196 C12.960928,1.5898358 14.390615,1.0156199 15.796864,0.60937196 C17.203113,0.20312399 18.468737,-2.4815418E-24 19.593736,-2.4815418E-24 z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154.842,231.937,0,224.93" RenderTransformOrigin="7.16469087632011,0.579533895579611" Stretch="Fill" Width="25.055" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path3" Data="M16.03124,1.1563877E-07 C16.31249,1.1563877E-07 16.566396,0.058593574 16.792959,0.17578049 C17.019521,0.29296741 17.210927,0.4335917 17.367177,0.59765339 C17.523427,0.76171507 17.644521,0.94140167 17.730458,1.1367132 C17.816396,1.3320247 17.859364,1.4999926 17.859364,1.6406169 C17.859364,1.9687403 17.777333,2.2265515 17.613271,2.4140506 C17.449208,2.6015496 17.09374,2.7421739 16.546865,2.8359235 C15.765616,2.9765478 14.914054,3.1992029 13.992179,3.5038889 C13.070305,3.8085749 12.140618,4.1601356 11.203119,4.5585711 C10.265619,4.9570067 9.347651,5.3984107 8.4492141,5.8827833 C7.5507772,6.3671559 6.7265589,6.8710596 5.9765594,7.3944945 C5.2265599,7.9179294 4.5820291,8.4413643 4.0429669,8.9647992 C3.5039048,9.4882341 3.1328113,9.9921378 2.9296864,10.47651 C3.4609361,10.335886 4.2421856,10.140575 5.2734349,9.8905758 C6.3046842,9.6405771 7.4648397,9.3944845 8.7539014,9.1522982 C10.042963,8.910112 11.386712,8.7030817 12.785149,8.5312076 C14.183585,8.3593334 15.515616,8.2733964 16.78124,8.2733964 C18.781239,8.2733964 20.249988,8.6171447 21.187487,9.3046412 C22.124986,9.9921378 22.593736,11.039008 22.593736,12.445251 C22.593736,13.382746 22.359361,14.273366 21.890612,15.117112 C21.421862,15.960858 20.792956,16.757729 20.003894,17.507725 C19.214832,18.257722 18.304676,18.956937 17.273427,19.605371 C16.242178,20.253805 15.164053,20.843646 14.039054,21.374894 C12.914055,21.906141 11.777337,22.374889 10.6289,22.781137 C9.4804634,23.187385 8.3984329,23.531133 7.3828085,23.812381 C6.3671842,24.09363 5.4570285,24.308473 4.6523415,24.456909 C3.8476546,24.605346 3.2187487,24.679565 2.765624,24.679565 C2.3906243,24.679565 2.0859369,24.585815 1.8515621,24.398316 C1.6171873,24.210817 1.4374999,23.988162 1.3124999,23.730351 C1.1875,23.472539 1.1054688,23.203009 1.0664064,22.921761 C1.0273439,22.640512 1.0078126,22.398326 1.0078126,22.195202 C1.0078126,21.788954 1.1328126,21.542861 1.3828124,21.456924 C1.6328122,21.370987 1.9999995,21.328019 2.4843742,21.328019 C3.4843735,21.328019 4.6249978,21.195207 5.906247,20.929583 C7.1874961,20.66396 8.4882766,20.304586 9.8085882,19.851464 C11.1289,19.398341 12.421868,18.867094 13.687492,18.257722 C14.953116,17.64835 16.078115,16.999915 17.06249,16.312419 C18.046864,15.624922 18.839832,14.921801 19.441394,14.203054 C20.042957,13.484308 20.343738,12.781186 20.343738,12.09369 C20.343738,11.453068 20.074207,10.992133 19.535144,10.710884 C18.996082,10.429636 18.031239,10.289011 16.640615,10.289011 C14.999991,10.289011 13.402336,10.410104 11.847649,10.652291 C10.292963,10.894477 8.8554638,11.164007 7.5351522,11.46088 C6.2148405,11.757754 5.03906,12.027284 4.0078107,12.26947 C2.9765614,12.511657 2.1640619,12.63275 1.5703123,12.63275 C1.3515624,12.63275 1.1484376,12.597594 0.96093768,12.527281 C0.7734378,12.456969 0.6093754,12.339782 0.46875049,12.175721 C0.32812558,12.011659 0.21484441,11.789004 0.12890696,11.507755 C0.042969519,11.226507 7.9676558E-07,10.867133 7.9676558E-07,10.429636 C7.9676558E-07,9.9140132 0.17968818,9.3671409 0.53906295,8.7890188 C0.89843772,8.2108967 1.3789062,7.6288683 1.9804683,7.0429338 C2.5820304,6.4569992 3.2851549,5.8749708 4.0898419,5.2968487 C4.8945289,4.7187266 5.7382783,4.1679481 6.6210903,3.6445132 C7.5039022,3.1210783 8.4062454,2.6367057 9.3281198,2.1913954 C10.249994,1.7460852 11.1289,1.3632746 11.964837,1.0429637 C12.800774,0.72265276 13.570305,0.46874778 14.273429,0.28124871 C14.976554,0.093749648 15.562491,1.1563877E-07 16.03124,1.1563877E-07 z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181.397,230.765,0,224.555" RenderTransformOrigin="6.76973666262973,0.590693262284116" Stretch="Fill" Width="22.594" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
    <Path x:Name="path4" Data="M9.2109315,2.8709165E-08 C9.3515565,2.8709165E-08 9.5195251,0.078124639 9.7148375,0.23437386 C9.9101498,0.39062308 10.089837,0.60155953 10.2539,0.86718321 C10.417962,1.1328069 10.558587,1.4570259 10.675774,1.8398346 C10.792962,2.2226471 10.851555,2.6328013 10.851555,3.0702972 C10.851555,3.5234219 10.839837,4.1991998 10.816399,5.0976309 C10.792962,5.9960658 10.765618,6.964811 10.734368,8.0038664 C10.703118,9.0429237 10.675774,10.066356 10.652337,11.074164 C10.628899,12.081971 10.617181,12.913998 10.617181,13.570245 L10.617181,13.828056 C11.67968,13.734307 12.511711,13.663994 13.113273,13.61712 C13.714835,13.570245 14.183585,13.531183 14.519522,13.499933 C14.855459,13.468683 15.109365,13.449152 15.28124,13.441339 C15.453115,13.433527 15.640615,13.429621 15.84374,13.429621 C16.609364,13.429621 17.20702,13.605401 17.636707,13.956962 C18.066395,14.308522 18.281238,14.679614 18.281238,15.070237 C18.281238,15.429611 18.140613,15.667891 17.859363,15.785078 C17.578114,15.902265 17.078114,16.015545 16.359364,16.12492 C16.21874,16.156169 15.976552,16.195232 15.632802,16.242107 C15.289053,16.288981 14.863272,16.347575 14.355459,16.417887 C13.847647,16.488199 13.273429,16.562417 12.632804,16.640542 C11.99218,16.718667 11.30468,16.804604 10.570306,16.898353 C10.539056,17.804599 10.503899,18.800688 10.464837,19.88662 C10.425775,20.972552 10.386712,22.074109 10.34765,23.191291 C10.308587,24.308473 10.269525,25.406123 10.230462,26.484243 C10.1914,27.562363 10.156243,28.546733 10.124993,29.437353 C10.093743,30.327974 10.070306,31.089689 10.054681,31.722498 C10.039056,32.355308 10.031244,32.788899 10.031244,33.023273 C10.031244,33.882644 9.8671811,34.495922 9.5390563,34.863108 C9.2109315,35.230293 8.7499943,35.413886 8.1562447,35.413886 C8.0156198,35.413886 7.8945261,35.292793 7.7929637,35.050607 C7.6914013,34.80842 7.6093701,34.476391 7.5468701,34.054518 C7.4843702,33.632645 7.4414014,33.14046 7.417964,32.577963 C7.3945265,32.015465 7.3828077,31.406093 7.3828077,30.749847 C7.3828077,29.437353 7.4101515,28.230328 7.4648389,27.128771 C7.5195264,26.027214 7.5859326,24.953001 7.6640575,23.906131 C7.7421825,22.859261 7.8124949,21.79286 7.8749949,20.706928 C7.9374949,19.620996 7.9843698,18.445221 8.0156198,17.179602 C7.656245,17.210852 7.277339,17.249914 6.8789018,17.296789 C6.4804646,17.343664 6.0898398,17.386632 5.7070276,17.425694 C5.3242153,17.464757 4.957028,17.496007 4.6054658,17.519444 C4.2539035,17.542881 3.9374975,17.5546 3.6562476,17.5546 C2.8437482,17.5546 2.1992173,17.437413 1.7226551,17.203039 C1.2460929,16.968665 0.87890568,16.699136 0.62109335,16.39445 C0.36328102,16.089764 0.19531237,15.79289 0.11718742,15.503829 C0.039062475,15.214768 -2.9646153E-21,15.007738 -2.9646153E-21,14.882738 C-2.9646153E-21,14.63274 0.06249996,14.449147 0.18749988,14.33196 C0.3124998,14.214773 0.57031213,14.156179 0.96093688,14.156179 C1.3515616,14.156179 1.8164051,14.187429 2.3554672,14.249929 C2.8945294,14.312429 3.4999977,14.343679 4.1718723,14.343679 C4.2968722,14.343679 4.4921846,14.33196 4.7578094,14.308522 C5.0234343,14.285085 5.3320278,14.261648 5.6835901,14.23821 C6.0351523,14.214773 6.4101521,14.187429 6.8085893,14.156179 C7.2070266,14.12493 7.6093701,14.09368 8.0156198,14.06243 C8.0312448,13.359308 8.0429635,12.613218 8.050776,11.82416 C8.0585885,11.035101 8.066401,10.281199 8.0742135,9.5624524 C8.082026,8.8437079 8.0898385,8.1913674 8.097651,7.6054309 C8.1054635,7.0194982 8.1093698,6.5780941 8.1093698,6.2812187 C8.1093698,5.6249739 8.1406197,4.9257586 8.2031197,4.1835729 C8.2656197,3.441391 8.3476509,2.7617069 8.4492133,2.1445206 C8.5507757,1.5273381 8.6679631,1.01562 8.8007756,0.60937199 C8.933588,0.20312402 9.0703066,2.8709165E-08 9.2109315,2.8709165E-08 z" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="205.727,221.132,0,223.454" RenderTransformOrigin="7.03586477018627,0.683653180122306" Stretch="Fill" Width="18.281" d:LayoutOverrides="HorizontalAlignment" Visibility="Hidden">
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Path.RenderTransform>
    </Path>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Are those paths individual letters?   If you want a simple left to right you could an opaque overlay that you animate to translucent.

Comment: Yeah the paths spell out the word 'Test'. I'll look into your idea but that may look similar to what I have going on right now - just not very natural in the 'handwriting' sense.

Comment: Would get a smooth exposure not steps.  Could have a gradient and put it at a slant to not look as mechanical.  Or key by slowly reduce the opacity.  But it would not be the same as a simulating a persons hand. That might be canvas and lot of dispatcher for timing.